# Restrict to only Persian chars in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform with some textboxes.

The form can be loaded in other languages too, like English! The requirement is that certain textboxes should accept only Persian chars for Example When a user types in Tex box 1, it should be in persian Whereas in if he types in Text box 2 and 3 it should be in English?

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean "persian digits" instead of "digits"? If it's not enough, please, provide some *examples*, e.g. what should be done with user input like "My test - 123 - ?!"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Could they mean _letters_ also (since Persian language is written with [a version of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet) Arabic script, while English uses Latin script, of course)? Of course digits are different too (in Iran they use [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals), while anglophones use Western Arabic Numerals, 1, 2, 3, ...).

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: that is the main question: which letters (digits, digits and arabic letters, something else) should be converted into which. I've provided an answer which is based on the example provided (digits only)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear, what "Persian Chars" are (e.g. what is Persian characters for "Hello"?). According to the example provided, it seems you want to convert **digits** into Perian ones, e.g.

```
0 - ۰
1 - ۱
2 - ۲
 ...
9 - ۹
```

If it's your case, you can use a simple *Linq* within `TextChanged` event handler:

```
using System.Linq;

...

//DONE: every digit within textBox1 is persian one
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender is TextBox box) {
    int ss = box.SelectionStart;
    int sl = box.SelectionLength;

    box.Text = string.Concat(box.Text
      .Select(c => char.IsDigit(c) ? (char) ('۰' + char.GetNumericValue(c)) : c));

    box.Select(ss, sl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the [CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory?view=netcore-3.1#system-globalization-charunicodeinfo-getunicodecategory(system-char)) method is used to detect the Arabic-Based languages including the Persian. The method returns [UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netcore-3.1) if you pass an Arabic letter.

So, if what you asking for is to allow the Arabic letters only to be entered, then handle the `TextBox.KeyPress` as follows:

```cs
// +
// using System.Globalization;
// ...

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && 
        CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(e.KeyChar) != UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }    
}
```

However, this solution won't prevent *pasting* none-Arabic letters from the system Clipboard. So a better solution is to derive a new class from `TextBox` to also override the `WndProc` method and trap the `WM_PASTE` messages to not paste the Clipboard text if it contains the wrong letters.

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
// ...

public class PersianTextBox : TextBox
{
    public PersianTextBox() : base() { }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && CharUnicodeInfo
            .GetUnicodeCategory(e.KeyChar) != UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter)
            e.Handled = true;
        else
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText() && Clipboard.GetText()
                .Any(c => char.IsLetter(c) && CharUnicodeInfo
                .GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter))
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```